# Is there a way to read in an excel file with multiple passwords on it in R?

Tags: r, excel, passwords

I have to bring in a directory for my project, but a few of the files are locked by more than one person. The password is the same, I just have to manually enter it for the files that require it more than once.

Here is the code that brings in the files:

```
library(excel.link)

#create file list

for (i in 1:length(data.files)){
total_data[[i]] = xl.read.file(data.files[i], header = FALSE, password = 
real_file_password, top.left.cell = data_location)
total_data[[i]][total_data[[i]]==" "] = NA
}
```

So, to reiterate, for the files that are locked by multiple people, I will have to manually re-enter the value that is "real_file_password".

If anyone knows how to solve this, that would be great! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If it's not currently supported you might want to file an issue here: https://github.com/gdemin/excel.link/issues

Comment: Still looking for a solution, but I have submitted an issue query!